# Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6A freeze after suspend, VPN blocks WiFi and bluetooth problems

Tags: sound, bluetooth, suspend, vpn

I recently bought Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6A (RX 6600M and R7 5800H), I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I have the following problems and I do not know how to troubleshoot so let me describe:

## Freeze after suspend

When I put the laptop in the suspend mode (via locking the screen and closing the lid), if I try to open, it freezes in the login page. I cannot click anything, mouse does not move. I need to press power button 5 seconds in order to hard shut down and then turn the PC on via power button again. I am seeing in the black screen some things about orphane nodes.

## VPN blocks WiFi

I am using ProtonVPN. I have installed it. This problem does not happen always, but when it happens, it is kind of annoying. When I log in my account, ProtonVPN is not running and in the status bar, VPN is not connected. Although I have internet access, I cannot access internet unless I run ProtonVPN or I click to "Connect to VPN" in the status bar. Sometimes, it just hangs. I need to manually find the PID, kill it via `kill -9 <PID>` and then run ProtonVPN again in order to access internet... And moreover, sometimes it doesn't help either. ps aux gives `nm-open+` as it is running protonVPN. When I try to kill the process via `sudo kill -9 <PID>`, nothing happens. Terminal freezes, I cannot quit terminal via CTRL+C. It is just annoying.

## Bluetooth problems

### Earbuds

When I log in to my account, if I turn on the bluetooth, I can easily connect my wireless earbuds. However, if I disconnect them and try to reconnect again I am seeing one of the following status in bluetooth status:

```
profiles/audio/avdtp.c:cancel_request() Suspend: Connection timed out (110)
```

or

```
bluetoothd[769]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:cancel_request() Suspend: Connection timed out (110)
bluetoothd[769]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:handle_unanswered_req() No reply to Suspend request
bluetoothd[769]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed for B0:F1:A3:38:D0:A9: Device or res>
bluetoothd[769]: plugins/policy.c:reconnect_timeout() Reconnecting services failed: Device or resource busy (16)
```

At this point, I need to issue `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service` and then manually connect my earbuds. When I restart the service, then the status is in following:

```
bluetoothd[7947]: Starting SDP server
bluetoothd[7947]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
bluetoothd[7947]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
bluetoothd[7947]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
bluetoothd[7947]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
bluetoothd[7947]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
bluetoothd[7947]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
bluetoothd[7947]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
bluetoothd[7947]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
bluetoothd[7947]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
```

After connecting manually, the status is:

```
...
bluetoothd[7947]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
bluetoothd[7947]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_B0_F1_A3_38_D0_A9/sep1/fd0: fd(42) ready
```

Now, if I go to Settings/Sounds, I can see my earbuds in Output device. That is nice. Configuration is High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink). However, the input device is Laptop's integrated microphone. If I try to set my earbuds microphone, my earbuds disconnects from bluetooth and tries to connects. Sometimes it connects, but sometimes it does not. I need to restart bluetooth service and manually connect my earbuds again. And it does not matter, in both cases, the microphone in earbuds do not work.

If I just disconnect my earbuds (via putting them into the box, without turning off the bluetooth or disconnecting manually from Bluetooth) the following is in the bluetooth.service status

```
bluetoothd[7947]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
```

### Headset (Sony WH-1000MX4)

Again, there is no problem if I log in to computer and turn on Bluetooth. Then my device can connect. However, if I disconnect (power off the headset), and try to connect:

```
bluetoothd[9085]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F8_4E_17_D6_65_58/sep1/fd0: fd(42) ready
bluetoothd[9085]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
bluetoothd[9085]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F8_4E_17_D6_65_58/sep1/fd1: fd(41) ready
```

Now, if I try to use microphone of my headset, bluetooth disconnects. It does not reconnect again. I need to manually connect headset to bluetooth. And sometimes, when I try to use headset's microphone, headset stays in "connected" state but there is no output or input. I see the following in status:

```
bluetoothd[9085]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_parse_rej() OPEN request rejected: Bad State (49)
```

The headset is in connected status at this point. It does not matter if I close the connected and try to reconnect. It does not connect. I need to turn off the headset and turn it on again. And sometimes, it does not help either. I need to issue `systemctl restart bluetooth.service` command.

I have no idea how to solve these 3 problems. I did the most investigation in bluetooth problem. If you can guide me, I can provide more information.

## Edit

`lspci` outputs as requested

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6600/6600 XT/6600M] [1002:73ff] (rev c3)
    DeviceName: Realtek RTL8111E Ethernet LOM
    Subsystem: Lenovo Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6600/6600 XT/6600M] [17aa:3ab1]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
```

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i audio -A3
03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 21 HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 6800/6800 XT / 6900 XT] [1002:ab28]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 21 HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 6800/6800 XT / 6900 XT] [1002:ab28]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: SK hynix Gold P31 SSD [1c5c:174a]
--
07:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [17aa:3841]
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x, snd_pci_acp5x
07:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [17aa:382b]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
08:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7901] (rev 81)
```

Comment: Did you check the lenovo forums? I've had massive power losses while suspending. It ended with a new bios that support that power mode for linux...

Comment: @kanehekili Oh, ok. Didn't know that. At least that is a start point. I was expecting this to be a problem with Ubuntu. I just gave my laptop info to provide more information. I will also try my luck in there too, thanks. But if someone has a solution, I am glad to hear their opinion

Comment: Well, your description is quite a mouth full. Starting with the first: show us your graphics card: `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3` and your audio hardware: `lspci -nnk | grep -i audio -A3`. Copy the answer from the terminal into your question

Comment: @kanehekili I added outputs as you requested